# Why did I fail to share smart home app to other Google account before it published?

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm developing a smart home app. When I use the same Google account to create the project in console and login in google home App, the smart home app is working successfully and it can get the device list.

But when I follow [the steps](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/testing-deploying#sharing_your_project) to share the project to another Google account(eg. abc@gmail.com), something is wrong. I use the abc@gmail.com login in google home App, I can see the smart home app project. But when I touch the project and login my service account to create account link, it login success and jump back to google home App. But it can't get the device list and the account link fail. I check my server's httpd logs, and I found that the Google Assistant service didn't send the SYNC intent to my server.

And I went back to login the account that create the project, it is working successfully and it can get the device list because my server can receive the SYNC intent.

I can't understand why the abc@gmail.com account couldn't get the device list, so I delete the viewer account(abc@gmail.com) of the project. But something amazing had happened! The google home App that login in abc@gmail.com still can see the project in home control after several hours!

I add a viewer of the project again, but it also couldn't get the device list bacause my server didn't receive the SYNC intent. I am no idea about the phenomenon.

Comment: I've been looking into some occasions when developers do not see a SYNC event happening.

Are you trying on two separate devices?

Comment: No, I am trying on the same google home device and the same Android phone. I just change the different google account.